# Quarkus connect to SQL Server database with kerberos

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, quarkus

When I try to run my Quarkus application with below command, the connection is established and working fine.

```
mvn clean compile quarkus:dev -Djava.security.krb5.conf=<path-to-my-krb5.conf-file>
```

When I want to deploy the application and package it with `mvn package` and then want to run the jar file, the connection to the database cannot be established.

```
java -jar -Djava.security.krb5.conf=<path-to-my-krb5.conf-file>
```

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Error message

```
"Unable to execute the validation check for the default DataSource: Cannot login with Kerberos principal <DB_USERNAME>, check your credentials. Kerberos Login failed: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:ed078e2e-addc-4582-9a83-68ad13040df1 due to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException (KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)"
```

Comment: can you provide with an error message and perhaps your connection string?

Comment: I have updated the question with the error message I get.

Comment: here you go, likely missing the Kerberos configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Everything is setup on the sql server. I just need to set the environment variable when running the jar file.

Comment: does this help? https://info.michael-simons.eu/2012/07/23/java-7-jaas-and-kerberos-single-sign-on-vs-newer-windows-systems/

Comment: I cannot make it work. The issue seems to be that I cannot set the property of the application when launching the jar file.

Comment: perhaps as the question with any error logs you have at https://dba.stackexchange.com/